# When I use Finch to play audio, can I actually do everything that OpenAL can do?

Tags: iphone, audio, openal, finch

When I use Finch to play audio, can I actually do everything that OpenAL can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked you couldn't do sound positioning with it. But then again you could modify it to support that.